# Enabling send-only email addresses as collaborators?

Tags: box-api

We've shared a folder via email access.  Would like to restrict receipt to a list of collaborators by email address.  By default, Box.com requires that each collaborator respond to an invite email and create a Box.com account.

One of our collaborators will be a system sending with a send-only email address.

Is it possible to setup send-only email addresses as collaborators?  Perhaps a way that we could "auto-accept" them?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Currently all email addresses must be confirmed Box accounts. A possible workaround is manually confirming the email addresses for these Box accounts.